# OS X Cocoa access appleSMC from sandboxed app

Tags: macos, motion-detection, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I want to access AppleSMC device from a sandboxed app , 
does anyone know what entitlement should I use to access Temperature sensors and FANs RPM?

here is the code I am using to access it :

```
kern_return_t result;
mach_port_t   masterPort;
io_iterator_t iterator;
io_object_t   device;

/*result =*/ IOMasterPort(MACH_PORT_NULL, &masterPort);

CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDictionary = IOServiceMatching("AppleSMC");
result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, matchingDictionary, &iterator);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK AppleSMC is not considered API and thus there's no corresponding entitlement to allow you to access it. (Source [Apple Developer Forum message 1082393](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1082393#1082393))

There might still be Apps in the AppStore that are not sandboxed as sandboxing was introduced later. See answer "[circumvent sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751171/mac-app-store-circumvent-sandbox-requirement/22761542#22761542)" for more details.

This also applies for the App in Question "MagicanPaster" which had it's last update in May 2011, long before sandbox was implemented.

You may distribute your app outside the Mac App Store, here a [brief overview by matt gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/releasing-outside-the-app-store/) on what it takes.

Comment: Thanks..But..But..how other apps accessing the info from the device then?

Comment: But, app store won't accept app that is not sandboxed -> Or am I wrong ?

Comment: The app I am talking about is MagicanPaster

Comment: So there is no way to make such app with more updated and advanced GUI ? and features ?

Comment: well it is super easy ! but how can i make ppl know about my new app ?

Comment: i mean is there any alternative app store ?

Comment: This is a completely new question and probably not suited for stack overflow. There are several alternatives and frameworks for billing, updating and licensing. Also invest in marketing :)

Comment: Yeah I know it was off topic well Thanks ! ,However I think Apple should have done such API... Because well ... honestly ... it's just six :(

Comment: Hi mahal , despite this was off-topic here is a blog where some guy explains everything about distribution outside of app store 
it would be nice if you could put it in your answer for future users
http://mattgemmell.com/releasing-outside-the-app-store/